# How to make my navigation menu responsive in css?

Tags: css

```css
.nav {
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 80px;
}
.nav > ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1100px;
}
.nav ul li {
  margin-top: 2em;
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13.3333px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.nav li ul {
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 50px;
}
.nav li > ul li {
  position: relative;
  right: 41px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  width: 340px;
}
.nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 340px;
}
.logo {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
  float: left;
  width: 148px;
  height: 56px;
}
#searchbar {
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14.6667px;
  font-style: normal;
  padding: 6px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: grey;
  width: 220px;
  height: 20px;
  : : -moz-placeholder
}
/* unvisited link */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav a:link {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 9px 13px;
}
/* visited link */

.nav a:visited {
  color: black;
}
/* mouse over link */

.nav a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #05437B;
}
/* selected link */

.nav li a:active {
  color: black;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">


  <ul>
    <img class="logo" src="img/uvlogo.png" />


    <li> <a href>home </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href> about us </a> 


      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">history</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">mission and vission</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">goals and standard of service</a>
        </li>


      </ul>

    </li>

    <li> <a href>products </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">eyeglasses frames</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">sunglasses</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">contact lenses</a>
        </li>


      </ul>






    </li>
    <li> <a href> services </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href> blog </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href>contact us </a> 
    </li>

    <li>
      <input id="searchbar" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I my navigation menu that when you zoom in browser it doesnt go down.
what i want to do is you zoom in your navigation menu it will go down. i want to edit this in css only

[See it on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/803dgwwx/)

Answer (score 0):

Add media query's, here is the complete list, if you don't yet know how to use them just drop a comment and i'll happily help you out

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}
/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}
/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Hey, im curius about that media thing, i think its bootstrap? How to do that ?

Comment: It's not bootstrap it's standard CSS. You add this form to your stylesheet and edit the style of your website according to the size of the screen. Also was my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

This (below) is not a great approach for a fully mobile friendly menu, but this will adjust it's width to the browser window when you narrow it done:

```
.nav > ul
{
margin: 0  auto;  max-width: 1100px;
}
```

Use `max-width:`in stead of `width:`

http://jsfiddle.net/803dgwwx/1/

For a fully mobile ready menu you might want to look into using the Bootstrap framework. Check out [Smartmenus](http://www.smartmenus.org/) also. It is easy to use, and also support accessability.

Comment: Hey thanks :) it works! but there a problem again, when my menu goes down, it intersects other object. like this. http://jsfiddle.net/803dgwwx/4/

Comment: How do you want your menu to work?

And: Could you post any of the javascript that do the toggle of the menus? The css and the html is not complete without the JS toggle I guess you are utilizing. At least there is no toggle in the jsfiddle.